# Inserting into SQLite database with parameters from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parameters, sqlite

I want to insert list items into a SQLite3 database with parameters, but it doesn't work.. and I don't even get any errors.

Here is my code:

```
strSQL = "insert into tbltrans2 (transid, flddate, itemcode, itemname, qty, price, total, btw, btwper) values ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Using cn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\POS.s3db; Version=3;"), _
    cmd As New SQLiteCommand(strSQL, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.String).Value = txtTransId.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Date).Value = txtDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", DbType.Double)

    cn.Open()
    For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
        cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.Tag
        cmd.Parameters(3).Value = ls.SubItems(0).Text
        cmd.Parameters(4).Value = (ls.SubItems(1).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(5).Value = (ls.SubItems(2).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(6).Value = (ls.SubItems(3).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(7).Value = (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text) / 100) * (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text)).ToString("#,##0.00")
        cmd.Parameters(8).Value = Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(strSQL)
     Next ls
     cn.Close()
 End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...just erase the values ?... then in the cmd.parameters.add.(Dbtype.String).value =txtTransId.Text.... just put it in the text all the value..

```
strSQL = "insert into tbltrans2 (transid, flddate, itemcode, itemname, qty, price, total, btw, btwper)"
Using cn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\POS.s3db; Version=3;"), _
    cmd As New SQLiteCommand(strSQL, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.String).Value = txtTransId.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Date).Value = txtDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add( DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(DbType.Double).Value = "The TEXT HERE"

    cn.Open()
    For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
        cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ls.Tag
        cmd.Parameters(3).Value = ls.SubItems(0).Text
        cmd.Parameters(4).Value = (ls.SubItems(1).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(5).Value = (ls.SubItems(2).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(6).Value = (ls.SubItems(3).Text)
        cmd.Parameters(7).Value = (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text) / 100) * (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text)).ToString("#,##0.00")
        cmd.Parameters(8).Value = Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(strSQL)
     Next ls
     cn.Close()
 End Using
```

Comment: Why not use named parameters?